# Achieving restricted polymorphism from concrete file

Tags: gf

Let's say I want to write a code that greets people, but for some reason, I don't want to greet a person called John, and I want GF to generate this kind of sentence.

### Abstract Version

I knew that this kind of result is achievable from the abstract file such as follow: `GreetingFromAbstract.gf`

```hs
abstract GreetingFromAbstract = {

  flags startcat = Sentence;

  cat
    Relation;
    Sentence; 
    Verb Relation; 
    Noun Relation;
    


  fun
    MySentence : (rel : Relation) -> Verb rel -> Noun rel -> Sentence;
    Say : Verb RelA;
    Mike : Noun RelA;
    John : Noun RelB;
    RelA, RelB : Relation;
}
```

And the concrete file would be like this:
`GreetingFromAbstractEng.gf`

```hs
concrete GreetingFromAbstractEng of GreetingFromAbstract = open SyntaxEng, ParadigmsEng, IrregEng, Prelude in {
  lincat
    Sentence = Phr; 
    Verb = V3; 
    Noun = N;
    Relation = {s : Str};


  lin
    MySentence _ action person = sayHi (action) (person);

    Say = mkV3(say_V) (noPrep) (to_Prep);
    Mike = mkN("Mike");
    John = mkN("John");
    RelA, RelB = {s = ""};


  oper
    -- Generate the final sentence
    sayHi : V3 -> N -> Phr =
      \v, n -> mkPhr(mkUtt(mkImp(mkVP
                                  (v)
                                  (mkNP (mkN "hi"))
                                  (mkNP (n)))));
   
  }
```

### Puzzle

But let's say for some reason I don't want to do that from the abstract file but from the concrete. I want the person that is writing the names to decide which person to say hi to, and which is not.

### Concrete Version

According to my problem, I wrote this code: `GreetingFromConcrete.gf`

```hs
abstract GreetingFromConcrete = {

  flags startcat = Sentence;

  cat
    Sentence; Verb; Noun;


  fun

    MySentence : Verb -> Noun -> Sentence;
    Say : Verb;
    Mike : Noun;
    John : Noun;
}
```

And the concrete: `GreetingFromConcreteEng.gf`

```hs
concrete GreetingFromConcreteEng of GreetingFromConcrete = open SyntaxEng, ParadigmsEng, IrregEng, Prelude in {
  lincat
    Sentence = Phr; 
    Verb = {v : V3 ; rel : Relation}; 
    Noun = {n : N ; rel : Relation};


  lin
    -- MySentence first judge if these two given variables are a good match
    MySentence action person = case <action.rel, person.rel> of {
      <RelA, RelA> => sayHi (action.v) (person.n);
      <RelB, RelB> => sayHi (action.v) (person.n);
      <_, _> => sayHi (action.v) (mkN(nonExist))
      };

    Say = {v = mkV3(say_V) (noPrep) (to_Prep); rel = RelA};
    Mike = {n = mkN("Mike") ; rel = RelA};
    John = {n = mkN("John") ; rel = RelB};


  param
    Relation = RelA | RelB;

  oper
    -- Generate the final sentence
    sayHi : V3 -> N -> Phr =
      \v, n -> mkPhr(mkUtt(mkImp(mkVP
                                  (v)
                                  (mkNP (mkN "hi"))
                                  (mkNP (n)))));
   
  }
```

### Problem

My solution is obviously not the best to offer since it would result in generating 50% empty sentences when using the command `gr | l`, which would get worse the larger the parameter `Relation` is.

### Questions

1- Is there any way to force abstract to give only matched parameters from the concrete file?
2- Or Is there any possible way to ask abstract to give another parameter when not matched from concrete instead of just generating the empty line using `nonExist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your questions, no and no.

#### Better workflow in the GF shell

If you want a less annoying workflow in the GF shell, you can `gr` several sentences at once, then it's more likely to get some that linearise. Like this:

```
GreetingFromConcrete> gr -number=10 | l 
say hi to Mike
say hi to Mike
say hi to Mike

say hi to Mike




say hi to Mike
```

To get rid of the empty lines, you can use the `?` in the GF shell to pipe an external command:

```
GreetingFromConcrete> gr -number=10 | l  | ? tr -s '\n'
say hi to Mike
say hi to Mike
say hi to Mike
say hi to Mike
say hi to Mike
```

The `tr -s` removes duplicated instances of a character, in this case the line break, and you won't have empty lines in the output.

#### "Overgeneration" in GF grammars

The way you've translated the selectional restriction task from abstract syntax (dependent types) to concrete syntax (parameters) is perfectly fine, that's the standard way things are done in GF. I have suggested a similar transformation in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049806/syntax-error-when-trying-to-use-dependent-types-in-gf/68051897#68051897) (scroll down to *3. Alternative way of making this grammar without dependent types*).

Often a GF grammar is embedded into a larger program. It doesn't matter if the GF grammar is overgenerating—the Python/Haskell/… program takes care that only the wanted trees are used, and none of the unwanted trees. I've written about that previously [in my blog](https://inariksit.github.io/gf/2020/10/07/new-distinctions-gf.html#softcore-add-constructions-with-default-implementations).